# php single quote search

Tags: php

I want to search for ***mc'd*** in my database, but I use `mysql_real_escape_string`.

But nothing is found because it will output ***mc\\'d***

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

`mysql_real_escape_string` should return single quotes escaped with only one backslash, so my wild guess is that you have magic_quotes_gpc turned on in your php.ini. Turn that off, and it'll be ok.

Comment: magic_quotes_gpc is deprecated anyway, so it's good to turn it off.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [PHP Data Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead of `mysql_query()`.  Then you don't need `mysql_real_escape_string()`, because PDO takes care of correct parameter passing internally.  (It'll use bind parameters if the database supports them, otherwise it'll do the escaping for you.)

This is safer, from an SQL injection standpoint, than constructing raw query strings by hand and having to remember to escape everything.  The parameter values are given separately from the SQL so there's no possibility of malicious input changing the structure of the query.

Answer (score -1):

Use addslashes while inserting in the database and use stripslashes while fetching from the database.

and in your condition its adding two slashes to `'` so i think it is due to you magic quote is on.

So it will be better if you turn off the magic quote and then make the search.

So after turn off the magic quote it will give `md'c --> md\'c`.

Hope this will helpful for u..

Comment: The `addslashes` function is a very poor method of escaping data for SQL queries. Undoubtedly one of the more dangerous methods available. - You should use the `mysql_real_escape_string` function, or better yet, the method suggested by Wyzard.